# Get name starts with particular substring

Tags: mysql, sql, string, select

I am trying to get the name which startet with this substring `ZOB`. In my table I have stop name `ZOB/Hauptbahnhof Bussteig 5` and I want to get it as result back.

With the query below the result is empty.

**query:**

```
Select stop_name from behaviour where stop_name like 'ABC' and mac = ? LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a wildcard (`%`) in the `like`'s argument:

```
SELECT stop_name 
FROM   behaviour 
WHERE  stop_name like 'ZOB%' AND mac = ? 
LIMIT  1
```